# What is the name of groups? in odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo-10

After Create group and view it here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvxKd.png

I want aLso view the group in this form

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdl9j.png

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please, take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will be useful for you and the community.

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing correctly you need to add security group in user form.

If yes then here is the answer:

- First you need to go to your custom module.
- Create folder named 'securtiy' and inside that folder create 'security.xml'

  (Name is not specific if you want to change file name then you can.)
- Add following code:

  `<record id="group_module_name" model="res.groups">
      <field name="name">group_name(any string you want)</field>
      <field name="category_id" ref="category_name"/> (This line is only for if you want to show group under specific category)
      <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/> (Automatically checked this group that you specified in 'eval' after checked 'group_module_name' group.)
  </record>`

**Refernce link:**

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/security/account_security.xml

**Comments's answer:**

Ok,
then here is your user's pop up view that is shown in your reference image.
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/views/res_users_views.xml#L117

See by this attrs the **groups** will not showed up in the pop up view,

attrs used by odoo: `attrs="{'invisible': [('id', '>', 0)]}"`

change according to your need.

Comment: I add group ,then i want use the group in xml name but can not found it

Comment: For hide the field ? can you see the group in user's form?

Comment: After create group i want view it in another form

Comment: Can you please tell me the requirement for it,
you can use groups to hide fields which are defined in odoo view file

Comment: I want view the group in this form https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdl9j.png

Comment: hello @Nourhan Given answer above in main answer

Comment: Yes I had given you the answer
Please see the heading 'Comments's answer:' in my answer.
Edit the view (I had given you path)

Comment: No ,i take the name from this view but it is not static ,it change when install app in another database , the photo in question @Saumil gauswami

Comment: Not static?.. be more specific.

Comment: if i add group later,this name will change automatic

Comment: Yes, I understand groups h dynamic name , so you can do is put that domain and change like this:-  attrs="{'invisible': [('id', 'not in', [%(your_module_name.your_group_xml_id).id])]}"